# How to display the bar value on top of each bar in a grouped bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotations, bar-chart

I read a couple of questions like mine, but no one seems to have the same problem that I'm experiencing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

facebook_users = [10, 14, 19, 17, 17, 13, 10]
twitter_users = [10, 18, 22, 17, 15, 11, 7]
linkedin_users = [4, 10, 20, 18, 20, 17, 11]

group = ['13 - 17', '18 - 24', '25 - 34', '35 - 44', '45 - 54', '55 - 65', '65+']

mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["#3B5998", "c", "grey"])

def bar_group(classes, values, width=0.8):
    plt.xlabel('Age groups (in years)', weight='semibold')
    plt.ylabel('Percentage of users (%)', weight='semibold')
    total_data = len(values)
    classes_num = np.arange(len(classes))
    for i in range(total_data):
        bars = plt.bar(classes_num - width / 2. + i / total_data * width, values[i], 
                width=width / total_data, align="edge", animated=0.4)
    plt.xticks(classes_num, classes, rotation=-45, size=11)
    plt.legend(['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'LinkedIn'])

    for rect in bars:
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')


bar_group(group, [facebook_users, twitter_users, linkedin_users])

plt.show()
```

I'm getting the bar label only on top of the last bar of each group, but i need to display the value on top of each bar of each group, how can I do this?

The current plot:
[image: Here's what I'm getting:]

Comment: [How to plot and annotate a grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493864/7758804) shows an easier way to annotate grouped bars, using [`plt.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).

Comment: Remove the loop `for rect in bars`. Then add `ax = plt.gca()` followed by `for p in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(p, label_type='edge')`, which works from `matplotlib v3.4.0`. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Prci.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move your `for` loop for writing the bar values (`plt.text`) inside the previous `for` loop. The problem is that you write the bar values after plotting all the three bars and so, once you come out of the plotting `for` loop, the variable `bars` contains only the values of the gray bars (the `LinkedIn` data) and hence you see the values only on top of gray bars. I am just writing the necessary part below. rest code remains the same.

```
for i in range(total_data):
    bars = plt.bar(classes_num - width / 2. + i / total_data * width, values[i], 
            width=width / total_data, align="edge", animated=0.4)
    for rect in bars:
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!