# How to create grouped bar plots in a single figure from a wide dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following df:

`test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'res1': [1,2,3], 'res2': [4,5,6]})`

[image]

I would like to plot (ideally, in one chart) the data, so I can compare res1 with res2 separately for each row (each name).

I have tried to achieve something similar, but I suppose that there is a simpler and more elegant solution that would also allow me to have it all in one chart with name as a group on x-axis.

```
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
    sns.barplot(x=test_df.iloc[i,1:].index.tolist(), y=test_df.iloc[i,1:].values.tolist())
    plt.title(test_df.iloc[i,0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This can be done with `seaborn.barplot`, or with just using `pandas.DataFrame.plot`, which avoids the additional import.
- Annotate as shown in [How to plot and annotate a grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63493530/7758804)

  - Add annotations with [`.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which is available with `matplotlib 3.4.2`.
  - The link also shows how to add annotations if using a previous version of `matplotlib`.
- Using `pandas 1.3.0`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, and `seaborn 0.11.1`

### With [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- This option requires setting `x='name'`, or `res1` and `res2` as the index.

```py
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'res1': [1,2,3], 'res2': [4,5,6]})

# display(test_df)
  name  res1  res2
0    a     1     4
1    b     2     5
2    c     3     6

# plot with 'name' as the x-axis
p1 = test_df.plot(kind='bar', x='name', rot=0)

# annotate each group of bars
for p in p1.containers:
    p1.bar_label(p, fmt='%.1f', label_type='edge')
```

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'res1': [1,2,3], 'res2': [4,5,6]})

# set name as the index and then Transpose the dataframe
test_df = test_df.set_index('name').T

# display(test_df)
name  a  b  c
res1  1  2  3
res2  4  5  6

# plot and annotate
p1 = test_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)

for p in p1.containers:
    p1.bar_label(p, fmt='%.1f', label_type='edge')
```

[image]

### With [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

- Convert the dataframe from a wide to long format with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), and then use the `hue` parameter.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'res1': [1,2,3], 'res2': [4,5,6]})

# melt the dataframe into a long form
test_df = test_df.melt(id_vars='name')

# display(test_df.head())
  name variable  value
0    a     res1      1
1    b     res1      2
2    c     res1      3
3    a     res2      4
4    b     res2      5

# plot the barplot using hue; switch the columns assigned to x and hue if you want a, b, and c on the x-axis.
p1 = sns.barplot(data=test_df, x='variable', y='value', hue='name')

# add annotations
for p in p1.containers:
    p1.bar_label(p, fmt='%.1f', label_type='edge')
```

- With `x='variable', hue='name'`

[image]

- With `x='name', hue='variable'`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The data could be formatted more easily, but it can be represented as a single graph by converting the data format to a vertical format and specifying a bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'res1': [1,2,3], 'res2': [4,5,6]})
df = test_df.set_index('name').unstack().to_frame(name='values')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'level_0':'categ'}, inplace=True)
sns.barplot(x='name', y='values', hue='categ', data=df)
```

|  | categ | name | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | res1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | res1 | b | 2 |
| 2 | res1 | c | 3 |
| 3 | res2 | a | 4 |
| 4 | res2 | b | 5 |
| 5 | res2 | c | 6 |

[image]