# Align label to 2 barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I need your help. I am practicing data analysis and now I am trying to visualize my findings.

May I know how to align the label to their respective barplot, I want them to be at the top position of the barplot.

[image]

I hope someone can help me in this one. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot and annotate a grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493530/how-to-plot-and-annotate-a-grouped-bar-chart)

Comment: This might also help: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html this one help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This code helps bar alignment and adds a label above it.

```
sns.set()

labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
entra_engaged = entra_total_engaged['TOTAL ENGAGED ENTRA']
entra_conversion = entra_total_conversion['TOTAL CONVERSION ENTRA']

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.4

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,8))
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, entra_engaged, width,label='Engage')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, entra_conversion, width, label='Conversion')

ax.set_ylabel('Total')
ax.set_title('MILK')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Hope this will help someone too